# Preselect a UITableViewCell from a segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, segue, null

I am using Storyboards and have a viewcontroller transition from one in which I want to pre-select a cell of a UITableView in the destination view controller.

prepareForSeque in the source viewcontroller passes a string value into a NSString of the destination viewcontroller.

What I want to do is on loading the destination viewcontroller, have the UITableView load with  the cell that matches the string value that was passed via the segue call...

Problem is - the UITableView is nil when I try to access it in viewDidLoad of my destination viewcontroller...I wanted to make a call to selectRowAtIndexPath from there...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In prepare for segue, you can reference the destinationViewController and make assignments or other calls to it.

I would recommend doing an

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *yourCellId;
```

in your viewController.h

Then in prepare to segue, you can so a `[[segue destinationViewController] setYourCellId:yourstring]` and it will set that value.

Then in viewDidLoad you can access yourCellId, as it will be set after the init, and before viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Make a property in your `destinationViewController.h` like this `@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *selectedString;`.
In `prepareForSegue`, after you have instantiated the destinationView, call `destinationViewController.selectedString = someSelectedString;`.
Then make the segue. Inside DestinationViewController.m, do something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(bool)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //Here you do whatever check you are doing to find out 
    //which row the selected string is in, and put it in
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndex = //Whatever datasource-way you can figure out
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndex animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```